# XBee ATIA command error

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I am using Xbee S8 (XB8-DMUS). and trying to implement Led-Switch example http://examples.digi.com/lights-motors-more/802-15-4-digital-output-with-an-led/

But xbee S8 returns ERROR on AT command console.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't give a lot of information; but if you look at step 3:

> If you’re not familiar with configuring radios using AT commands,
>   review the steps in the Basic XBee 802.15.4 Chat tutorial, which walks
>   you through configuring CoolTerm to program the radios.

Something in your configuration has to be screwed up, assuming you followed the previous steps correctly.

That tutorial mentioned is linked here:

[Cool Term Setup](http://examples.digi.com/get-started/basic-xbee-802-15-4-chat/3/)

I'd make sure you were perfect here in the configuration. If not, then something with your HW setup is off.

Comment: The xbee module that i use Xbee 865-DMUS (S8), does not support MY and IA, i.e. ATMY & ATIA commands return ERROR